# 1990's Choose your path kids story

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember a 90's book that was large format (A6 maybe), hard cover with completely illustrated pages that looked almost fine-art painted. All I remember is that two children where invited to a theme park/island by their uncle/dad, and each two pages is a particular themed stage of the park. The end reveals the entire thing is staged (some parts play out as scifi or horror). But it's like a 4D experience for the kids. I don't remember the name and I only remember the two swimming thru a stinking, submerged mechanical giant fish, and a giant brain "having bad thoughts about them", and a crashing stage coach going into a medieval castle, and the final room where the behind-the-scenes is making the park work. What is the name of this book???

Comment: *"large format (A6 maybe)"* Paper sizes are counterintuitive. The higher the number, the *smaller* the page! http://desguide.com/wp-content/uploads/standard_paper_sizes.jpg

Answer (score 3):

[Demian's Gamebook Web Page](http://www.gamebooks.org) has a very large list of choose-your-path style books, so I searched for books whose title or description has the word "park" (but without 'Jurassic') by putting the following into a google search:

site:www.gamebooks.org "park" -jurassic

Unfortunately there were a lot of books with scary amusement parks and the plot descriptions weren't super-detailed, but [this result](http://www.gamebooks.org/amazing.htm) mentions a title called "The 4-D Funhouse" so that made me think of the "4D" in your description--does this cover look familiar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the exact same book! I took it upon me to look through all the choose your own adventure books on amazon (75 pages)... and I found it!
it's the Haunted Castle by Leo Hartas

Comment: Can you provide any more evidence that suggest the two are the same?